# Is there any interesting data I could obtain from Application_End() parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, global-asax

In my ASP.NET application that I deploy on Windows Azure I want to log as many useful data as possible. There's `Application_End()` method:

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

which is invoked with `sender` being [`System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320861/57428) and `e` being just `System.EventArgs`. With such parameters all I can do is just log their types which isn't very useful.

Can I obtain any useful data from these parameters? Are there cases when `Application_End()` is invoked with parameters that have other - more useful - actual types?

Comment: What do you mean by *interesting*? What might be interesting for you might not be interesting for me. So could be a little more specific about the information you are looking for in this event? Remember that there's no `HttpContext` when this event is called which narrows down the kind of things you could grab from it.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov: I have no idea, but maybe I can find the reason why the application ends or anything else that would help me identify the context of the call.

Comment: No, you cannot find out why your application ends. Possible reasons you should be looking for: 1. `web.config` file changed 2. `global.asax` file changed 3. some of the files in the `bin` folder changed or a new file was added or deleted 4. your application hit CPU/memory threshold limits that were defined by the administrator and IIS decided to recycle it in order to free the consumed resources.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Turns out it is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS, `class HttpRuntime` included, sources can be downloaded. Careful analysis shows that indeed the event parameters are always the same and convey no useful information. The call stack for the event is also useless - it is always

```
my Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(HttpContext context, MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs, HttpSessionState session)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Dispose()
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.Dispose()
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ReleaseResourcesAndUnloadAppDomain(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

but... There is [`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.shutdownreason%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that can be retrieved from within `Application_End()` and that is set by `HttpRuntime` when the application shutdown is being initiated.

So the "interesting data" is `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason`.

Also see [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14855938/57428)