# How do I programmatically find why Application_End() is invoked?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

`Application_End()` is invoked when my application pool is stopped which can happen for a number of reasons, including automatic pool recycle or changes in the folder from which the application is served.

The call stack will typically looks like this:

```
my Application_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(HttpContext context, MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs, HttpSessionState session)
at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Dispose()
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.Dispose()
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ReleaseResourcesAndUnloadAppDomain(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

which is completely useless.

How do I programatically find why it was called?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's [`System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.shutdownreason%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property that indicates why the application is being terminated. Its value can be retrieved from inside `Application_End()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this one really helped me! It seemed that I was modifiyng a file in the application's /bin directory on startup which triggered the Application_End().