# Get trigger reason from Application_End() in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP MVC application. In Global.aspx I have Application_Start() and Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e).

I am aware that Application_End can triggered when web.config changes, site stopped/restarted etc. But I want to log what exactly triggered Application_End. `sender` holds the details but I am unable to find to which class I should typecast it.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855938/how-do-i-programmatically-find-why-application-end-is-invoked

Comment: Thanks @TimAlonso, ApplicationShutdownReason is  providing the required information. Is there any doc that describe how to use `sender` and `eventargs` in app lifecycle?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at HttpApplication's methods and events. This is where Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) is inherited from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?view=netframework-4.7.2