# Are Application_X event handler parameters ever useful?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, events, global-asax

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059139/57428) it's up to me whether I declare an ASP.NET application event handler in `Global.asax.cs` like this (no parameters)

```
protected void Application_Error()
```

or like this (two parameters)

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

so basically it boils down to whether I'm interested in those parameters. So far I see that `e` is a reference to `EventArgs` (not some descendant) and contains absolutely no data and `sender` is always a reference to `ASP.global_asax` type object that contains a reference to the class containing the handler (same as `this`) and a reference to an instance of `System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile` type.

Other handlers also don't seem to ever have useful parameters passed to them. For example, [`Application_End()` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14518861/57428) is always passed a reference to `System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory` and a reference to `EventArgs`.

So far I feel like I should just convert each of my `Application_?(object sender, EventArgs e)` handlers into just `Application_?()` form.

Is there ever a situation when those handler have useful (at least for debugging) parameters passed?